# On the continuity of Riemann Integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have the following equation

$$g(y)=\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x,y) dx$$

I know that $f$ is continuous in $x$ and $y$. But I would like to infer that $g$ is continuous in $y$. Can I do this?

EDIT:

I wont write down the function here, since it is huge, but I can guarantee that:

$f$ is differentiable in both $x$ and $y$

$\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} f(x,y) = \infty$

I could try to solve the integral, but I do not know if I'm able too. Applying some theorem that guarantees continuity would be great, but now I see I would need further hypothesis.

Comment: Yes, but it requires the notion of uniform continuity. Are you familiar with that? **Edit:** I didn't notice the infinite integration limit. In this case, you need a further hypothesis.

Comment: Regarding extra hypotheses: See for example the [Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem). It is true for Riemann integrals, because the Riemann integral is a special case of the Lebesgue integral. But the proof is easier for the latter.

Answer (score 5):

Counterexample without further hypotheses:
$$
  f(x,y)=\begin{cases}ye^{-xy}&y>0,\\0&y\le0.\end{cases}
$$
Then
$$
  g(y)=\begin{cases}1&y>0,\\0&y\le0.\end{cases}
$$

Comment: I think Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem does not help me, neither does Monotone convergence theorem. It is because, in my application I have $\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} f(x,y) = \infty$, that is, my function does not converge pointwise to anything. 

Sorry for not mentioning that before.

Comment: @user60111 Bad behaviour as $y\to\infty$ shouldn't be a problem for continuity, if you can use Lebesgue for any bounded set of $y$ values.